# How can I give access to a single wordpress folder to some 3rd person in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, nginx, multiple-users

The owner and group of 'www/website1' is root:www-data and I can tinker with its contents or configuration as root or sudo user.

But now, I want to create another website named website2 (under 'www' directory itself), whose access needs to be given to a friend of mine (so he could easily configure this website for me as he pleases). But he shouldn't be able to tinker or even view any other directory in my OS even with sudo.

For this purpose, I can create a new user in my Ubuntu OS and create a ftp login id/pw for him. But I saw/found that, along with 777 access to this website2, he also, automatically, is getting a read access to full root folder and all its sub-folders.

Is there a short way to control this, so that he could only see the required 1 (or 2 folders), but no more than those specified? Also, I don't want to tinker with the properties of all other folders of my full OS, one by one.
Thanks.

Comment: Add the folder `www/website2` as a symbolic link to a folder that the friend has FTP access to.

Comment: If the FTP server will run chrooted, symbolic link won't work. And if the FTP server will run non-chrooted, he will be able to access other files and folders anyway, as long as he knows the actual path.
However, if you set www/website2 as home folder of {user2} and run FTP chrooted, then he should not be able to get out of the directory.

Comment: @Jos Friend hasn't been given access to anything yet. That was my question. How to give him access to only one sub-folder of /var/www without letting him see any other folders in my system. Also, I didn't understand, what'll happen if I create a symblink to the folder I want him to give access of?

Answer (score 0):

`www-data` is the key here: that is the group. You can add users to a group so they have access to files and directories based on the groups permissions.

The command would be:

```
 usermod -a -G www-data {user2}
```

{user2} will then be able to change files that are connected to this group  (besides the files he can change that he owns himself).

If needed you could even create a new group, connect that one to the 2 users and restrict user2 to specifically those files connectecd to that group. Apache uses www-data as user but that user can also have more than group www-data.

> I saw/found that, along with 777 access to this website2, he also, automatically, is getting a read access to full root folder and all its sub-folders.

chmod 777 is never the answer unless you also include the sticky bit.

Comment: I think the main problem before me is how to stop this 'user2' from having 'read' access to my full folder hierarchy. Also, if I make him member of 'www-data' he'll have access to all of my other website folders, which I never want.

Comment: Then create a new group specifically for that situation (2nd part of the answer)

Comment: then 'www-data' group will no longer have access to that 'website2' folder and I'm afraid if my site should stop working due to some, other, unforeseen, implications of the same.

Answer (score 0):

use the following command:

`setfacl -R -m user:{user2}:rwX www/website2`

That should give user {user2} full access to www/website2 and everything within that directory.

**Edit:** I just noticed that your problem is that {user2} has read access to other directories than www/website2. These directores usually have, by default, read access enabled for "other", ie. for any user - that's why {user2} can read them. Without removing this access, you cannot prevent {user2} from viewing them.
The only method is - as I stated in the comment under your question - locking {user2} in FTP chroot jail, so that www/website2 will be the root directory for that user. Check if your FTP server supports that.

Comment: I've my own Ubuntu 18.04 droplet/virtual server. If I make /var/www/website2 as that user2's home folder, will he not able to read any other folders (normally i see that all new users have 'read' access to all folders, not just their own 'home' folders)? And if your answer is 'yes, he won't have access to any other folder other than his own 'home' folder, then, 2nd query, if in future I want to give some other /nginx/conf.d/w.conf file's access to this user2, will I able to do so? How!!

Thanks very much.

Comment: (comment #1/2) If the user logs via FTP only, as you have mentioned, then you can configure the FTP server (often it is configured so by default - you must check) to put the user in chroot jail once he logs in. Chroot jail means that the user cannot get out of his home directory, because the home directory is seen as the root directory for him. Other directories simply "don't exist". This has nothing to do with permissions system. Of course that won't work if the user can log in via ssh, it is for FTP access only. So you have to restrict him from login in ssh daemon configuration.

Comment: (comment #2/2) It is common that on a *nix system, all users have read access to most system directories (but not all), they only don't have access to other users' home directories. It is just how the permissions system is designed. If you want the user to be unable to read some directories, you must remove read access for "other" from all these directories - there is no other way. However, I wouldn't recommend this with system directories, as you must be absolutely sure that you don't break something by mistake by doing this.

Comment: thank you @raj Can you send me some good link to implement 'chroot jail'. Also, user will be able to login thru terminal using his password (not ssh pub/pvt keys). My whole purpose is that I want to give access to somebody so that he could work freely on one of my wordpress websites, but couldn't see or touch any other thing. He might (I'm not sure yet, if he WOULD NEED or not) need terminal access some time. I think I'll remove him from 'sudo' group so that he couldn't do any harm with that command either. Am I thinking right?

Comment: For chroot jail, you must check the FTP server documentation. But if the user will be also able to login via terminal, it makes no sense to configure chroot jail for FTP. As for the read access, any user MUST have read access to system directories, otherwise he won't be able to run any commands or even login. So you should define only a set of specific directories that you want the user will NOT be able to see, and remove read access for "other" from them. As for sudo, yes, you shoud definitely remove the user from sudo group, thus he will have only read access and won't break anything.

Comment: BTW. regular users should not be in sudo group anyway, only the user who will act as admin should be in that group. Putting an user in the sudo group means effectively give him access to everything.

Comment: Thank you Raj, you're helping much. I checked 'chroot jail', but that's too much for me. So I've decided that I'll rather simply hide other users 'home' folders and other websites folders (those are under /var/www) from him. Just tell if I remove 'read' permission for 'others' from these folder locations, (hope) this won't break my websites or any other thing from working, would it?

Comment: You must check how your webserver is set up, because it has to have read access to all website directories, otherwise it won't work.
If these directories are owned by webserver user, then you can safely remove access for "other". But if they are owned eg. by root, you cannot do this, as the access for "other" also provides access for the webserver user.

Comment: again, thank you. Although I've accepted your previous suggestion that I should accept the fact that normal non-sudo users are setup to be able to have 'read' access over normal ubuntu folders and there is no harm in that.

Comment: Regarding your latest comment, it has shed some new light and enlightened me as how the ubuntu works. So now just one thing, if all permissions are default & 'www-data' is the group owner of the web folders (inside /var/www), can I stop normal other websites folders inside 'www' to have no (read) access to 'others'? Or will it break my wp websites/something? This way I hope to restrict this new normal user to at least not peek into my other websites.

Comment: Again, it depends how your webserver/Wordpresss/websites are set up. I don't know this, so I can't answer your question. If, for example, your website folders/files are owned by "www-data" (or whatever user your webserver runs under), you can restrict other users from reading them without breaking your websites. If, on the other hand, they are owned by "root" (and group "root") then access for other users is necessary for websites to function. You must check this in detail yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But I had already told/cleared in my last comment that 'www-data' IS the group owner of my webroot (or www) folders. And, I think, your comment (almost) clears it that if in Ubuntu+Nginx 'www-data' is the group of the www folders, then I can restrict 'others' from reading those folders without breaking anything.
In other words, if /var/www/websitename has root as its owner and 'www'-data' as its group, then it may have the permission 750 without any problems. Have I understood correctly @raj?

Comment: But I'm still not clear about another doubt, in which you said the /home/folders have no/zero permission for others, but its not so. They've 754 permission (i.e 'read' for 'others')

Comment: Yes, if website folders are owned by 'root:www-data' you can safely set permissions to 750, I think. As for the home folders, I also think you can safely remove the read permission for others.